# How can I organize a database with products and users?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design

I am currently trying to organize a *django database model* for an online shop-system with users and products.

My code:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bought_products = models.ForeignKey(MarketProducts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class VendorData(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sold_products = models.ForeignKey(MarketProducts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class MarketProducts(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(VendorData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=b'shop/media/images/')
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    dislikes = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I organize a good working system so all the products a user bought are saved inside the **bought_products** column and all the products a vendor sold can be saved inside the **sold_products** column. Do I have to use a ForeignKey for that or is there something more suitable for this situation? Also, if there is anything unwise about the existing structure of the database model (for example the current *image* field column only saves the link but not the image itself which is kinda weird...), please feel free to correct me :).

Many thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

In this case I suggest to make `bought_products` and `sold_products` instances of `ManyToManyField` because the same product can be bought by multiple Users and sold by multiple vendors

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Could you please give me a code example of how to implement a many to many relationship properly in my case?

Comment: well I think it's better if you have a look to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would start by reading the following documentation on django auth customization. Seems like that would help you out a little bit.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Additionally, I think you need to better evaluate your data modelling to make each model more explicit/clearly defined. See example below:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(VendorData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=b'shop/media/images/')
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    dislikes = models.IntegerField()


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

From there I would construct a separate model which would store the customer purchased items. Since you already have a model which stores the vendor to product data, you shouldn't need anything additional to identify how many sales a particular vendor has.